# Add or merge another document or template based on user choice

Tags: docusignapi

If I have a radio button in a DocuSign form, is it possible, after a user has selected a value in the radio button and signed the document, to add in another document and or template (merge them?) into the same envelope, then send it to another recipient?

Example, say there's a question "Is this a Legal matter", and the signer selects "yes", can we receive that envelope, add in another document at the end, and then send it to another recipient (i.e. the Legal department)?

Answer (score 0):

Envelopes have different status. Once an envelope is Complete, it cannot be modified.
An envelope that is in-route can still be modified using what we call the "correct" flow but there are sets of rules and restrictions on what can be changed. read all about "correct" here - `https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-correct-documents` and see if that may work in your case.